# Browser Compatibility issue in the tooltip

Tags: jquery, css

I was working on a tooltip (to show content in it while typing). It was working fine on chrome but only before I tested it on Mozilla Firefox. The tooltip is positioned at the bottom of the text-area box in Chrome Browser (which is what I want) but in Mozilla Firefox it shows up at some random place but the tooltips for all the text-areas show up at same random place on focussing the text-area. I know its a CSS issue but still attaching all the related code.

**CSS**

```
.tooltip
{
    color:#0D776e;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:calibri;
    min-height:25px;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:0 0.5%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    display:none;
    z-index:500;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:32px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("textarea").focus(function()
    {
        var targetArea = $(this);
        targetArea.siblings('div').fadeIn(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"}).html(targetArea.val());
    });

    $("textarea").blur(function()
    {
        var targetArea = $(this);
        targetArea.siblings('div').fadeOut(400).css({"background-color":"#E7F1F0","border":"1px solid #86BBB6"});
    });

    $("textarea").keyup(function()
    {
        var targetArea = $(this);
        targetArea.siblings('div').html(targetArea.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: is parent div set to `position:relative` or `absolute` ? Help a lot if you include html

Comment: Well I guess your problem is the missing definition of `left: xx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember from a prior post you are using this in a `TD`. `TD` will not accept position so wrap all the contents in a `DIV` with `position:relative` so that the tooltip can refernce it's position from the `DIV`

Comment: I'm using a table for this purpose, so its not possible to wrap it up in a div. There are more columns than shown in the post.

Comment: wrap inner contents of `TD` in a DIV with class that has position

Comment: is a problem related to using tables..they have quirks which is why they are not used much for layout anymore